# I'm having problems getting a button to display the right size in Wordpress using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, button, resize

I have used the button with icon generator at:
[https://www.html-code-generator.com/css/button-generator]

I have successfully created the button, and have deployed it on the wordpress site at: [https://www.boardingtheark.net/reservations-2]

I copied and pasted the appropriate coding, but the button displays to tall, and I can't seem to resize it properly.

The coding is below:

```
     .css-button {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #735a46;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #735a46;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #735a46;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #735a46 10%, #e0cea6 100%);
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}
.css-button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #e0cea6 10%, #735a46 100%);
}
.css-button-text {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 18px;
}
.css-button-icon {
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff29;
    box-shadow: inset rgb(0 0 0 / 14%) -1px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

I have tried changing the padding but have only been able to affect the button width. I need to make the button a little shorter, but I can't figure out how to do it. Thank you for looking and for any insite you may offer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `<br>` tag in your code below the tag with the class:
`css-button-icon`
If you delete that you can simply modify the height of your button using the height property. example: `height:30px;`

[image]

Comment: I have looked and looked and can not find the <br> I've look on the actual page and in the CSS coding and still do not see it.

Comment: @K.Kessler the Wordpress editor you're using is most likely inserting the br tags. Try to remove line breaks from the button using the editor

Comment: Wondering if there is another solution to make this happen? I have tried removing the line breaks to no avail. Thank you again for your insight.